# Why does lim_{n\to\infty} work in my LaTeX document?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

`lim_` is not a command in LaTeX because all commands begin with a back slash.

However, why does `lim_{n\to\infty}` work in math mode? What is `lim_` if it is not a command?

Comment: just `lim_` is treated as ordinary text and `\lim_` is the maths way of using limits.

Comment: @HarishKumar I believe you are wrong. `lim_` is not treated as an ordinary text. `lim_` is standalone `l`, standalone `i` and standalone `m` with a following token as a subscript. To make it an ordinary text you have to put `\mathit{lim}`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The macro for the limit operator is `\lim`.

Without the `\`, it just treated as three characters `l`, `i`, `m`.  This is no different that `$xy$` representing a product of two terms `x`, and `y`, so `$lim$` is a product of three terms: `l`, `i`, `m`. So with `$lim_{n\to\infty}$`, the subscript is applied to the `m` term.  Perhaps the meaning is more obvious if you write and equivalent statement:

```
$ l  i  m_{n\to\infty}$
```

Note that without the `\` the three letters are in italics, representing variables.  The operator `\lim` is not in italics representing an operator.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\begin{document}
$lim_{n\to\infty}$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}$

\[ lim_{n\to\infty} \]
\[\lim_{n\to\infty} \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
$\lim_{a\to b}$

In Textmode $\lim\limits_{a\to b} \frac{a}{b}$ or \\

in Displaymode $\displaystyle \lim_{a\to b} \frac{a}{b}%
\end{document}
```